# Using Ajax with PHP to auto-select from drop down list

Tags: php, ajax, forms, drop-down-menu, get

I'm using a drop down list to select an option that with fill in a form based on items that have been saved. All I'm trying to do is obtain a form id from a drop down, then query the database for the correct values to go in the fields. The Ajax request works correctly, however ,since the form is called from a function, when a value is selected that same function is called again so there are 2 forms generated.

So the flow of information is.

1. when the page loads, function create_event is called which displays a form.
2. If an item is selected from a drop down (in create_event) to fill out some options, that same create_event function is called again via ajax, so that same form loads again.

Here's where the form is called

```
if($_GET['form_id']){ //a value was selected from the drop down list
    if(isset($my_username)){  //make sure the user is signed in
        $form_id = $_GET['form_id']; 
        $event->create_event($form_id);
    }
}
if($uri_2 == "create" AND !$_GET['form_id']){ //checks URI for create page and no form_id has been selected
    if(isset($my_username)){  //make sure the user is signed in
        $form_id = "";
        $event->create_event($form_id);
    }
}
```

How can I work around this? I'm fine with the page re-loading, but I don't know how to do that  without passing something visually through the URL (which I'd like to avoid).

Comment: Try looking into $_SESSION variables.  That should accomplish the task.

Comment: Specifically doing what with them? Set the form_id as a session?

Comment: Sure, all that data persists through page loads.  So set $_SESSION['form_id']=$_GET['form_id'] and then you no longer have to pass that through the url bar.  You could also pass form data: $_SESSION['form1']=$_POST; etc.

Comment: Gotcha. Just to make sure I'm interpreting this correctly, set the sesion, reload the page, check for session (and then destroy it after querying). Thanks!

Comment: make sure you put `session_start();` at the top of the pages so that it continues the session.

Comment: why don't you pass an extra argument through your ajax call with a flag for which form you are trying to load?